# Manage @XStreamAlias for interface reference

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I am new to xstream and I come across one situation as below.

```
<root>
 <category>
   <car></car>
   <cloth></cloth>   
 </category>
</root>
```

This is my demo XML. Here category can have either `car` or `cloth` as subnode but not both of them at a same time. I need help on how to define POJO class for this situation. I have tried this way.

```
@XStreamAlias("root")
public class Root {

    @XStreamAlias("category")
    private Category category;

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

Here `Category` is interface which is implemented by `Car` and `Cloth` class.

Implementation for `Cloth` class is as below.

```
@XStreamAlias("cloth")
public class Cloth implements Category {

    @XStreamAlias("name")
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


Root r = new Root();
Cloth c = new Cloth();
c.setName("xyz");
r.setCategory(c);

String xmll = XStreamUtil.toXml(r);
System.out.println(xmll);
```

Which resulted in following output.

```
<root>
  <category class="cloth">
    <name>xyz</name>
  </category>
</root>
```

desired output is as below

```
<root>
  <category>
    <cloth>
        <name>xyz</name>
    </cloth>    
  </category>
</root>
```